# Trouble running two web applications on the same domain on nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I would like to have an nginx server hosting web applications on the same domain, with different paths.
For example, 
http://example.org/booksapp/signin.html should point to the first app,
and http://example.org/shoesapp/signin.html should point to the second app

within my host, I have two folders, one for each app:
/var/webfolder/booksapp and /var/webfolder/shoesapp

my nginx configuration is the following

```
server {
    server_name example.org;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location /foodapp {
        root /var/webfolder;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /shoesapp {
        root /var/webfolder;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
}
```

This configuration does not work. My browser just shows a blank page when trying to load either web application. 
Meanwhile, the nginx log files shows a list of 404 for every resource that the apps are trying to load.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of web apps are these? Static sites?

Comment: no; HTML and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your html files to use the right paths.

Your "booksapp" lives at `example.org/booksap/`, the html pages must load any static resource using that same path.

This is the head section of an example html file. If you deploy this to any of your sites it will not work, nginx can't find "normalize.css" and "styles.css" unless you specify the right path. Right now nginx is acting as a router between the two apps, you can't ask for just a file, you must specify which app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>sakura demo</title>
  <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
```

It should be:

```
  <link href="booksap/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="booksap/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Comment: This was related to my problem. I had a <base href="/"> which caused all resources to be searched in the root (which incidentally redirected to /usr/share/nginx/html)